# Flag not updating on user profile?

Tags: 7, views, panels, users, flags

I'm using panels to display user profiles and each profile has a 'follow' flag (non global).
I've used a view called 'follow-users' to capture few users and one of the field within that 
View is the same 'follow' flag link.

When someone flags a user within 'follow user' view the flag on user profile still stays unflagged

Can anyone please help to figure out why it’s happening?

Thanks

Comment: just to clarify - User A sees a list of other users in a View, and clicks on the follow flag for User B. When User A then navigates to User B's profile, the flag link does not show that User A is following User B?

Comment: @Geoff this is exactly what happening.

Comment: when User A navigates back to the View, is it flagged as follow?  are you sure you using the same Flag in both places?

Comment: Ahhh... thanks @Geoff I was using the wrong flag. All sorted now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a look at the flag set up in each of your displays, and make sure you are using the same Flag - it's an easy oversight if you have multiple types of Flags and can cause this sort of behaviour.